# Wi-Fi not working with Ubuntu 14.04 in HP spectre

Tags: wireless, hp

I followed instructions on many posts and no results so far, I have no Wi-Fi connection.

Some useful information:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: nfc0: NFC
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
dvorak@dvorak-spectre:~$
```

****kernel version:
dvorak@dvorak-spectre:~$ uname -rm
3.16.0-39-generic x86_64

---

dvorak@dvorak-spectre:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a1e (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an acer module loaded and you say it is a HP computer, so do this

```
echo "blacklist acer-wmi" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot and see if wireless is still hard blocked with `rfkill list all`

Comment: you're a genius man... I've spent three days trying to figure this thing out (Linux Amateur)... it totally worked.. thanks so much